# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/FilterRegistration

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6.0 and I am trying to code a very simple project of "word counts". I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/FilterRegistration

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;


public class WordCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("scrittura.txt");
    JavaRDD<Integer> lineLengths = lines.map(s -> s.length());
    int totalLength = lineLengths.reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println("TOTAL: " + totalLength);

    JavaRDD<String> flat = lines
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "").split(" ")));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> map = flat
            .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(x, 1));

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> reduce = map
            .reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);

    System.out.println(reduce.collect());

    sc.stop();
    sc.close();
}}
```

This is my log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/FilterRegistration  at
>   org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.(ServletContextHandler.java:136)
>     at
>   org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.(ServletContextHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.(ServletContextHandler.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:101)
>     at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:78)     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:62)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachTab(WebUI.scala:62)  at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:61)  at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.(SparkUI.scala:74)  at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:190)    at
>   org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:141)  at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:466)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
>     at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:16) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.FilterRegistration    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 18 more

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>examples</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
   </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785021/updating-jetty-7-to-jetty-8-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filt) (wrong servlet api dep)