# Spring security 4.x incompatible with Servlet 2.5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are trying to introduce Spring Security 4.0.2 into a Spring MVC application which uses Spring 4.2.3 but also is running on servlet 2.5.  I am having trouble configuring Security:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.FilterRegistration$Dynamic
```

I believe this class is only in Servlet 3.0.  Is it possible to use Spring Security 4.0 with Servlet 2.5?  Or should we regress to Security 3.2?

Comment: We use Spring Security `4.0.3.RELEASE` with Spring `4.2.4.RELEASE` and Servlet API `2.5` and don't face any problems either at compilation or during application start up or at runtime.  I have created a [small sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35732187) from our production application that you can check.  You will see that it compiles and loads fine.  If you could post a similar minimum sample that demonstrates the problem, someone can check.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is you are using Jetty and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785021/updating-jetty-7-to-jetty-8-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filt) explains your situation.

> The `javax.servlet.FilterRegistration` class was introduced in Servlet
>   3.0. This exception suggests that you have still libraries of an older Servlet API version in your runtime classpath which got precedence in
>   classloading.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Java configuration demands this class.  I used the old XML configuration and things worked fine.