# ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext in Jetty hello world

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jetty

I am trying to follow the http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld tutorial (with Eclipse).  The project compiles fine.  However, when I hit the localhost server I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext
```

Now it looks like that is defined in [Java EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) what do I need to add to the build path to get this to work?  I have installed Java EE but I am not sure where to go from there.

I am trying this with

jetty-all-8.0.4.v20111024.jar

servlet-api-2.5.jar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That class is [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) in Servlet 3.0 which is part of Java EE 6. Jetty 7 as mentioned in that tutorial is a Servlet 2.5 container. Servlet 2.5 is part of Java EE 5. You need to upgrade to Jetty 8 which is a Servlet 3.0 container.

Downloading and installing the whole Java EE pack as available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) makes no sense as that basically gives you the Java EE reference implementation Glassfish back, not Jetty, while you need a newer version of Jetty, not Glassfish.

You also need to make sure that you don't have downloaded an arbitrary `servlet-api.jar` file from somewhere and placed it in the classpath while you already have a fullworthy servlet container like Jetty at your hands (which is a classic beginner's mistake to circumvent compilation errors they faced on the `javax.servlet` API).

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)
- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: hmmm that might explain it I was just using the latest release of Jetty (8.0.4) and servlet-api(2.5). I'll try it with different versions and see if that works.

Comment: You should not have loose `servlet-api.jar` files wandering around in classpath. Remove them all. A servlet container like Jetty provides it **already** by itself. Related food for reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: yes, it works now. however the tutorial tells to download servlet-api.jar, and will not compile without it.

Comment: Great. Not all tutorials are necessarily good. The best ones are Oracle's own ones. You basically need to reference Jetty's own libraries in compiletime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you installed [Java EE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/) which has no AsyncContext. Update to Java EE 6 which has that:
 [Java EE 6 Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/)

Comment: thanks for the response. However, I downloaded Java EE 6 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html and restarted.  Is there something I need to add to a class path somewhere?