# ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext in Jetty hello world in eclipse

Tags: java, jetty

I have followed the link http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld tutorial (with Eclipse). and also looked at the existing stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037492/classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-asynccontext-in-jetty-hello-world)

I am using the aggregate jetty 8.0.0.jar and 8.1.3.jar along with the servlet-api-2.5.jar. I have added these 2 jars to the class path and also included the slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar too.

I am still getting

`
    2012-05-23 15:23:06.813:WARN:oeji.nio:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.<init>(AsyncHttpConnection.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$SelectChannelHttpConnection.<init>(SelectChannelConnector.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$SelectChannelHttpConnection.<init>(SelectChannelConnector.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.<init>(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.createEndPoint(SelectorManager.java:938)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:283)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

   Caused by: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.<init>(AsyncHttpConnection.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$SelectChannelHttpConnection.<init>(SelectChannelConnector.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$SelectChannelHttpConnection.<init>(SelectChannelConnector.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.<init>(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newEndPoint(SelectChannelConnector.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.createEndPoint(SelectorManager.java:938)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:283)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

`

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you need the servlet api 3, not 2.5. [AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) was introduced in Servlet 3.0, it doesn't exist in 2.5.

Comment: correct, and you should also update to a newer version of jetty8, 8.1.3.v20120416 is solid

Comment: Servlet api 3.0 can be downloaded from [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) **Edit:** Servlet api 3.0 solves the problem as @Kai Sternad answered. To be specific regarding providing link, the reason was because servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1 version doesn't solve the problem. However the link for servlet api in the [tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld) have this version available as **latest** download, which doesn't contain class [AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) and hence doesn'