# NoClassDefFoundError (AsyncContext ) for Jersey on AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I'm running my server application on AppEngine (Java), using Jersey (2.10.1). My application ran fine on a staging server, and worked after deployment to production.

Then some time a few hours later, we started seeing request failures with a NoClassDefFoundError for AsyncContext logged (see stacktrace below). It's happening in virtually all of my Jersey services, whether they return JSON, or Redirects. AppEngine still only supports Servlet 2.5 API, but Jersey 2.10 is supposed to be fine with that.

Restarting the appengine instance helped fortunately/unfortunately. Any suggestions for what's causing th

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:439)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:534)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:482)
at com.annkh.filters.JerseyFilter.doFilter(JerseyFilter.java:27)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:419)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl$ExtensionImpl.complete(AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.commit(ResponseWriter.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
    ... 52 more
```

I

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037492/classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-asynccontext-in-jetty-hello-world and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037492/classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-asynccontext-in-jetty-hello-world

Comment: @RafaelZeffa Thanks. Unfortunately unless I'm missing something, that answer (both links are the same) suggest upgrading to servlet-3.0. That's not possible on Google AppEngine at the moment.

Comment: sorry, the other link is it, there many people waiting by support servlet 3.0 too: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091