# Error while oprating javac -d: invalid flag? If I correct it, another package-not-found error appeared instead

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, classpath, javac

I'm a newbie in Java EE. And I was following the steps of the book Head First Servlets and JSP to create a simple web application.

I wrote a simple servlet in Java. Now, I am planning to compile it and to put the class in the development environment. I'm not using any built tools, just with javac command in Windows. The servlet's path is D:\Learning Exercises\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java. And I plan to put the class file under the directory D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\WEB_INF\classes\com\example\web\

The commands on the book are:

```
% cd MyProjects/beerV1
% javac -classpath /Users/bert/Applications2/tomcat/common/lib/servlet-api.jar:classes:. -d classes src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java
```

I ran these command under Windows:

```
D:\>cd D:\Learning Exercises\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\src\com\example\web
D:\Learning Exercises\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\src\com\example\web>javac -classpath D:/"Program Files (x86)"/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/lib/servelt-api.jar;-d D:/"Program Files (x86)"/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1/WEB_INF/classes/com/example/web BeerSelect.java
```

The system return an invalid flag error to me (I'm using a non-English OS. The following information is translated to English by myself):

```
javac: Invalid: D:/Program Files (x86)/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1/WEB_INF/classes/com/example/web
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
-help to list all the valid options
```

Why did that happened? Am I using this javac -classpath -d command in a wrong way?

**Actually, I think there is something wrong with the ";" here in front of "-d". If I replace the ";" with a space, there won't be this invalid flag error, BUT a "package javax.servlet doesn't exist" error instead, which is realy confused since I include the servlet-api.jar right here!**

The corrected codes go here:

```
D:\Learning Exercises\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\src\com\example\web>javac -classpath "D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\lib\servelt-api.jar" -d "D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\WEB_INF\classes\com\example\web" BeerSelect.java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spelling of `"servlet-api.jar"` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use your directory navigation this way

```
"D:/Program Files (x86)/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/lib/servelt-api.jar"
```

Comment: Thx. I tried, but it didn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Angdi This should help  D:\Learning Exercises\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\src\com\example\web>javac -classpath "D:/Program Files (x86)/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/lib/servlet-api.jar" -d "D:/Program Files (x86)/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1/WEB_INF/classes/com/example/web" BeerSelect.java

Comment: I am thinking of the same thing. It did help for the invalid flag problem, BUT a "package javax.servlet doesn't exist" error appeared instead, which is realy confused since I've already include the servlet-api.jar right here! O_O

Comment: Not sure why its giving that error. This setup is working fine for me. Can you check if you have spelt the jar name correctly in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Use '\' for directory navigation in windows. [ '/' is for linux]. So try this:

```
D:\"Program Files (x86)"\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\lib\servelt-api.jar; -d D:\"Program Files (x86)"\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\WEB_INF\classes\com\example\web BeerSelect.java
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem...I tried but it's not helping.

Comment: one more try, take care of white-space: **javac -classpath** D:\"Program Files (x86)"\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\lib\servelt-api.jar; **-d** D:\"Program Files (x86)"\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\WEB_INF\classes\com\example\web BeerSelect.java

Comment: Still not helping...Please see my updates to the question. Thx!!

Comment: but you using this: **d:/** !! Use this way **d:\ **.

Comment: Well, I did tried. I corrected my command like this: javac -classpath "D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\lib\servelt-api.jar" -d "D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\webapps\HeadFirstSnJ_Demo1\WEB_INF\classes\com\example\web" BeerSelect.java And the system gave me a package javax.servlet doesn't exist" error instead

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193228/compile-error-package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist) . Hope this helps.