# "Access is denied." while compiling servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have to compile Prime.java this way:

`javac –extdirs <path-to-appserver>/lib –Xlint Prime
.java`

in my case it looks like

`C:\Users\Mateusz\workspace\zad2\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes> >javac -extdir <D:\xampp\tomcat>\lib -Xlint Prime.java`

The response from cmd is "Access is denied."

How can I solve this ?

I set my path and java_path correctly.

Comment: Do you have permission to access the directory? Try running the prompt as admin.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message, or is "Access is denied" the whole message?

Comment: @JGrice yes, I checked it twice.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it is whole message

Comment: Your command line has some stray '>' and '<' characters in it -- those aren't actually part of what you're trying to execute are they?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill without '<''>' strays i've got  
`javac: invalid flag: -extdir
Usage: javac <options> <source files>`

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the cmd as Administrator?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx

Do all the directories you affect exist and do you have write privileges for them?

EDIT:

You have to remote the "<" and ">" you are basically trying to write to a file. It should work like this:

```
javac -extdirs D:\xampp\tomcat>\lib -Xlint Prime.java
```

EDIT2:

The parameter is "extdir**s**" not "extdir" (without "")

Comment: yes, I checked it twice. Also I change my directory from C:\ to D:\ in case of avoiding accesibility to C:\

Comment: C:\Users\Mateusz\workspace\zad2\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes>javac -extdir D:\xampp\tomcat>\lib -Xlint Prime.java

Comment: Here is the response `javac: invalid flag: -extdir 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>`

Comment: Sorry, try it like this:  C:\Users\Mateusz\workspace\zad2\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes>javac -extdirs D:\xampp\tomcat>\lib -Xlint Prime.java

Comment: Whoa! Amazing ammount of errors.. this in't good way..
Few examples:

`Prime.java:2: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^
Prime.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                               ^

Prime.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class Prime extends HttpServlet {`

Comment: You need to add the depedencies to your classpath. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193228/compile-error-package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist

Comment: and how can I add many of them (imports) to classpath? also I want to ask what about this kind of error `Prime.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class Prime extends HttpServlet {`?

Comment: Actually, with the edits I did answer the question. As you stated I am not able to comment. @Jan It would be great if you could accept the answer, since it solved the original question the moment you got the compiling errors.