# I am trying to inherit java class from servlet

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

When import

```
 javax.servlet.*;  javax.servlet.http.*;
```

it gives error  package javax.servlet does not exist

i am using jdk 1.8

Comment: Please refer to similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/9193228/5916727

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile error: package javax.servlet does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193228/compile-error-package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have **servlet-api.jar** and it should be set in classpath.