# jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Class [com.practice.MyServlet] is not a Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, classcastexception

I am beginner to working with servlet.
I am creating a servlet and but after running that i am getting error
Can anyone help me to resolve this.
**Error**

> Type Exception Report
>
> **Message Class [com.practice.MyServlet] is not a Servlet**
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
> prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> **jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Class [com.practice.MyServlet] is
> not a Servlet**
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:682)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1568)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Root Cause
>
> **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.practice.MyServlet cannot be cast to
> jakarta.servlet.Servlet**
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:682)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1568)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Note The full stack trace of
> the root cause is available in the server logs.

[Click here to see the Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i5LO.png)

**MyServlet.java**

```
package com.practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("test/html");
        out.print("<h1>This is get method of my servlet</h1>");
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.practice.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Edit your question with proper text. See [ask]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're basically physically including Tomcat 9.x (Servlet 4.0) specific JAR file in WAR and then writing/compiling code against Tomcat 9.x (Servlet 4.0) or older and then then deploying the WAR to Tomcat 10.x (Servlet 5.0) or newer. This is not the correct approach at all.

Since Tomcat 10.x (Servlet 5.0) the `javax.*` package has been renamed to `jakarta.*` package.

In other words, please make sure that you don't randomly put JAR files of a different server in your WAR such as `tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.4.jar`. This will only cause trouble. Remove it altogether and edit the imports of your servlet class from

```java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

to

```java
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
```

While at it, please also make sure that the root element of the `web.xml` is declared conform the Servlet API version of the target server, which is in case of Tomcat 10.x thus Servlet 5.0 (and thus *not* Servlet 3.1 which basically matches Tomcat 8.0).

```xml
<web-app
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
    version="5.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

#### See also:

- [Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [Tomcat 9 casting servlets to javax.servlet.Servlet instead of jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/tomcat-9-casting-servlets-to-javax-servlet-servlet-instead-of-jakarta-servlet-ht/)