# Cant install JavaEE in my computer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I tried to install JavaEE on my computer. I already have JDK 7 and Netbeans 7.1.2.

But when I try to install it, it shows this error..

> application needs version 1.6 or higher of java(TM)2 Runtime
>   environment.....

Comment: What version of JEE you are trying to install?

Comment: question would be ask on [Superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: ... and what JavaEE implementation?  If you're trying to install Glassfish, why not just install the Netbeans installer that includes Glassfish?

Comment: or ditch it and use spring ;-) then you won't need a hulking mass of EE server like glassfish, just tomcat and a few jars

Comment: @Asif tools commonly used by programmers are allowed here as per http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @fvu Well yeah its a _programming tool_ but its more related as OS specific installation purpose question rather than _use_ of that tool in programming.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The JDK installer for Windows doesn't do its job entirely right. Some registry keys for the JRE are missing. The Java EE installer is relying on them. You basically need to install JRE as well which you can get from http://java.com. You don't need to uninstall the JDK. Just install JRE over it, it'll set the proper registry keys and your Java EE installer will then continue.

Note that the Java EE pack basically contains the Glassfish server and optionally also bundles the Netbeans IDE. You can alternatively also just download and install Glassfish separately from http://glassfish.java.net. Or if you happen to have installed Glassfish already or already have another server like Tomcat or JBoss AS, then you don't need the Java EE pack at all.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)