# What is the difference between "Java EE SDK" and "Java EE Web Profile SDK"?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws

This is pretty confusing for me ! I just started learning\developing web services (i.e. `jax-ws`) and I'm unable to include `WSServletDelegate` so I thought it should be in the `Java EE SDK`.

So I went to the `Java EE` [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) and found these 2 items to sound as the closest to what I need:

---

**Java EE 6 SDK Update 4**

A free integrated development kit used to build, test, and deploy Java EE 6 applications.
Includes:

- GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
- Java EE 6 Code Samples
- Java EE 6 API Documentation
- Java EE 6 Tutorial
- Your First Cup: An Introduction to the Java EE Platform

**Java EE 6 Web Profile SDK Update 4**

A free integrated development kit used to build, test, and deploy Java EE 6 web applications.
Includes:

- GlassFish Open Source Edition Web Profile 3.1.2.2
- Java EE 6 Code Samples
- Java EE 6 API Documentation
- Java EE 6 Tutorial
- Your First Cup: An Introduction to the Java EE Platform

---

Both downloads contain the same contents but the **only** difference between both titles is "**Web Profile**" and the description for the latter says it's for developing "Web applications". The only thing I can think about is that the latter has jars related to `Servlets` or `JSP`, but shouldn't that already be included in the first download since `Servlets` and `JSP` are considered `Java EE` technology specs ?

And what if I go on developing using `Java EE` provided jars, should I **install** `Java EE` SDK on the machine running my application or is it ok to only include the needed jars in my classpath ?

Would someone please help me resolve that confusion !
Thank you.

Comment: This is answered in Glassfish's own site: http://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html. On a related note, this is perhaps also enlightening: [What exactly is Java EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)