# java ee sdk download cannot find jdk

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have been developing JSP, servlets, applets, stand-alone applications, and other java code using eclipse on my computer.  Recently, java was removed from my computer as part of an otherwise successful antivirus procedure.

Now, when I try to load eclipse, the message I get is that my system does not have a jre or jdk.

When I try to download java ee, I can only find  [these download options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html), which promise to provide the java ee sdk.

However, when I download and run the install files, the installer stops mid-way through the process to tell me I cannot proceed because no jdk was found on my computer.  It asks for me to manually point to the jdk, but I cannot do that because there is no jdk on my machine.  The only jdk download site that I can find is  [this one, which is for java se.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)  But ****I need java EE to develop jsp, servlets, applets, etc.****

I have not found any information explaining how to integrate the two.  In the past, I seem to recall just being able to do one java download.

Can anyone show me how to download the java EE jdk?

Comment: JEE does not include JDK. JSE does. You need to download and install the JSE before installng JEE.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java EE SDK from Oracle is indeed the GlassFish implementation. Note that you don't need to download a Java EE JDK to start developing applications on Java EE, instead you need a **Java EE compliant application server**. Knowing this, you have plenty of alternatives:

- Free Java EE Application Servers like [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas.html), [GlassFish v3](http://glassfish.java.net/) and [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) (do not confuse with Tomcat).
- Paid Java EE Application Servers like [WebSphere Application Server (aka WAS)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/) from IBM or [Oracle WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/cloud-app-foundation/weblogic/overview/index.html).

Why aren't [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) listed here? Because they are Servlet containers, no Java EE compliant web application servers.

IMO I would use a free AS like JBoss or GlassFish to start in the Java EE world.

Since the question is tagged with eclipse, if you will go with JBoss path, I heavily recommend to install [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) to get better help with JBoss AS usage, JSF, Hibernate, JPA and much more (DISCLAIMER: I'm not related with JBoss nor Red Hat in any commercial ways, just a satisfied user of these technologies).

If all what you want is to learn about JSP/Servlets to start with Java web development, then you just need to use Tomcat for being very lightweight. Then you can move on one of these Java EE alternatives.

Comment: Minor note related to the first sentence of your answer: it is GlassFish the (referense) implementation of the Java EE, not the other way. No offense )

Comment: @informatik01 yes, it is a reference implementation, that doesn't mean other vendors should follow it

Comment: Actually what I meant was the phrase itself. I.e. it should be "GlassFish is the implementation of Java EE", not "Java EE is GlassFish implementation".

Comment: @informatik01 you misunderstood the sentence. Java EE **SDK available to download from Oracle web site page** is indeed GlassFish.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Just the word "implementation" in the end confused me.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

?? That's where the JDK is, took me 5 seconds to google

Comment: Hm, just saw that your link is the same. This is the right link, you can develop JSP and servlets with the JDK.

Comment: why did this get downvoted? I'm using the JDK right now, which I downloaded from this link, and I can create JSPs ...

Comment: Actually the Java SE JDK **alone** is not enough. To be able to use servlets/JSP (and JSP pages are compiled to servlets too) you need at least servlets container, which has the appropriate implementation of the Servlets specification etc. (I'm not the downvoter...)

Answer (score 0):

Download from here:

[Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 SDK Update 4 (with JDK 7u11)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u4-jdk-7u11-downloads-1900532.html)

Good Luck ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And GlassFish **is** Java EE *reference implementation*. Just as a side note...

Comment: This is covered in my answer. Since looks like you're new to answering questions, I recommend you to read [the most voted Java questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes&pagesize=15) to understand the difference between an answer with a plain link and an answer that explains and provides different ways to help you move on.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am sorry, were your previous comments addressed to me? I didn't give an answer for the OP's question... My comment to your comment was "as a side note". Relax ) P.S. Using `@user` would definitely help

Comment: @informatik01 none of my comments in this answer were for you (I never send you the message with the @ thing)