# Java EE SDK 6 is not being installed on windows 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-6

I am successfully running 64 bit JDK. But I now need to install the Java EE sdk 6 on the windows 7 machine. I have downloaded "java_ee_sdk-6u4-windows.exe" from Oracle website. But when I try to install it, I get the error which is attached in the attached screenshot.[image]

I have double checked my java_home and class-path, they are perfect.

Any idea how to get it fixed.

Comment: Which 64-bit JDK do you have installed? Do you have both 1.5 and 1.6 installed?

Comment: i have installed jdk1.6.0_39 64 bit version and only this version of jdk is installed.

Comment: Did you try the install command line as shown in the dialog above?

Comment: yes, I did try that one too, but no success, do you want me to show that error too ?

Comment: Yes. A fundamental rule of SO questions if to _show what you've tried_ so we don't repeat work you've already done.  _Especially_ if you got a different error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave some more tries, and at the end, command worked with quotes on the jdk path.

`C:\Users\jsmith\Downloads>java_ee_sdk-6u4-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\ jdk1.6.0_39".`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In windows 7 64 bit installing the JDK misses some files (namely /lib/tools.jar) due to a permission problem in spite of the installation successful message.

#### Solution is

Reinstall the JDK 6 using Run as administrator then install the EE SDK using Run as administrator as well.

As BalusC answered EE SDK is all about an application server and an IDE and both are replacable. Yet when I started my EE studying I really enjoyed Netbeans 7.x coupled with Glassfish 3.1 as they provide many tools and shortcuts useful for Java EE starters.

#### A final tip

In windows 7-64 bit, either Netbeans or Eclipse has to be run using Run as administrator in order for either to start the Glassfish server from within the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The Java EE installer will indeed fail like that when you installed the JRE via the JDK. Most likely the JDK installer forgot some Windows specific registry keys or files for the JRE.

If you reinstall the JRE directly from http://java.com (you don't need to uninstall anything beforehand), then the Java EE installer should start to work (along some other Java programs relying on the JRE such as `eclipse.exe`! in Eclipse's case you should otherwise have edited the `eclipse.ini` to specify the path to the right JRE).

---

By the way, in case you're not aware of that, the Java EE SDK contains basically the GlassFish server along a bunch of documentation and optionally the Netbeans IDE. It's absolutely not a requirement if you want to go Java EE. You could for instance also just keep using Eclipse and setup Tomcat, JBoss or whatever server different than GlassFish. A lot of Java EE starters don't realize that. Even more, you could just download GlassFish individually as a ZIP file from its homepage at http://glassfish.java.net without the need for the whole Java EE SDK thing.

See further also [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee/7295697#7295697)