# Which kind of jstl should i use?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am learning how to use JSTL in my application.

When i was ready download it from Internet, I found there are **two kinds of JSTL**.
The first one is from http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs.html, another is https://jstl.java.net/. Though files' names are different, it seems they both works.

What's the different between them? Which one should I use?

Comment: Marked for close as primarily opinion based. My opinion: Go with Tomcat version, since it seems to be actively maintained.

Comment: @Andreas: It isn't completely opinion based. OP is asking for the difference between the two first and then asking for opinions. We can edit this question and make it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like as everything else in Java EE, JSTL is an **abstract** API. The concrete code is provided by the implementors. Oracle is one and Apache is another one.

Which one to choose is up to you.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)