# Integrate Hibernate into JSF project with Glassfish server

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsf, glassfish

I am using GlassFish server in Eclipse and  am trying to intergerate the `hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final` into the JSF project. I have tried several steps but without seccuss.

- I have Placed the Hibernate Jars inside the GlassFisch directrory `glassfish4\bin` and restarted the server.
- I placed them inside the following foloder `glassfish4\glassfish\bin` and restarted the GlassFisch server.
- I placed the Hibernate jars inside the WEB-INF/lib
- I added this part `.addResource("/resources/person.hbm.xml")` to the `CreatePersonDemo` class.
- I replaced the `jboss-logging.jar` inside the `glassfish4\glassfish\modules` directory with `jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar`

**CreatePersonDemo**

```
package com.backing;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.model.Person;



public class CreatePersonDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create session factory.
//      SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
//              .configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml")
//              .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
//              .buildSessionFactory();
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addResource("/resources/person.hbm.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create a session.
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("CreateStudentDemo");

    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GMapsYahooMeshup</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping resource="resources/person.hbm.xml" /> 
        <!-- <mapping class ="com.Model.Person" /> -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**person.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Person" table="person">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the person detail.
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="full_name" column="full_name" type="string" />
        <property name="email " column="email " type="string" />
        <property name="location" column="location" type="string" />
        <property name="pwd" column="pwd" type="string" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Person.Java**

```
package com.model;   

public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String full_name;
    private String email;
    private String location;
    private String pwd;
    public Person(int id, String full_name, String email, String location, String pwd) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.location = location;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFull_name() {
        return full_name;
    }
    public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }
    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jul 17, 2016 10:24:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.backing.CreatePersonDemo.main(CreatePersonDemo.java:22)
```

**Project structure**

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to add legacy and standalone Hibernate to a Java EE 5+ server which already offers JPA out the box? Why not just using standard JPA and if necessary swap out GlassFish's EclipseLink JPA implementation with Hibernate JPA implementation? All that struggle is unnecessary. Are you sure you're reading the right and up to date books/tutorials/resources on the subject?

Comment: @BalusC: I installed the JBoos Tools to Access the hibernate perspective in eclipse. Do u know a good example to integerate Hibernate into the Project from the Hibernate perspectiv?

Comment: @BalusC:if i want to wrok with EclipseLink and JPA in JSF project. should I create JPA Project or normal web dynamic Project and then add all required jars?

Comment: You don't need to add any Java EE related JARs if you already target a Java EE server such as GlassFish. Adding JARs is only necessary when you target a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096 and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: did you find a solution?