# How am I able to reference Entity Manager instance even if I don't have any implementation?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

In my java EE application , I wrote a simple bean that I referenced container managed entity manager like below

```
@Stateless
public class MessageService {

@PersistenceContext
private  EntityManager entityManager;
```

But even if I have only java EE 8 and H2 database dependencies on my classpath, I was able to reference and use EntityManager from my bean. Should not I have been have to have a JPA implementation on my classpath like Hibernate etc.?

Comment: Are you using an Application Server (JBOSS, Wildly, GlassFish, etc) to deploy your application?

Comment: Yeah . I am using latest Wildfly server to deploy my application. How do I know if required libs are contained in my deployed application?

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file?

Comment: I added persistence.xml file. But didn't supply any provider tag in the xml file. How does application server know which vendor to use for jpa implementation?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on your comments:

> I am using latest Wildfly server ...

And

> I added persistence.xml file

The answer is: **Wildfly will include for you some libraries in the Application's classpath when some conditions are met** ...

According to the documentation, in your case, it adds JPA subsystem and its implementation (Hibernate) when it detects either the use of `@PersistenceUnit` or `@PersistenceContext` annotation or other XMLs tags in some deployment descriptors ...

You can read more about this in:

[Wildfly Automatic Dependencies](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Developer_Guide.html#automatic-dependencies)

[Implicit module dependencies for deployments](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Developer_Guide.html#Implicit_module_dependencies_for_deployments)

**NOTE**: The most recent documentation that I found was Wildfly 26 ... however, this is something that they've done since Wildfly 8 ...