java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
My application use spring 6.1.7, hibernate 5.6.7.Final, Wildfly 28,
My web.xml context-param is
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-root.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext-slis-security.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext-slis.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

My applicationContext-slis.xml has the followig bean:
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="hk.housingauthority.slis.model" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

When start server, I see many error like

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-slis.xml]:
javax/validation/ValidatorFactory     at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
... 154 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
javax/validation/ValidatorFactory     at
java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at
java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3543)   at
java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3529)     at
java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2225)  at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:113)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784)
... 161 more

is the error due to the class "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"?
Then how to fix it?
------------------------  Edit -----------
but I check the source in
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.0.9.RELEASE/source-code/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.java

And no import or reference to jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory, so why the error message mention

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory..."

And in hibernate 6, I see the following statement, what does this means?

Hibernate ORM 6.x is officially only supported as a JPA provider.
Please use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with
JpaTransactionManager there instead.


Spring 6 isn't compatible with Hibernate 5 nor Javax Validation. You need Hibernate 6 and Jakarta Validation.

The same goes for Wildfly 28, it is a Jakarta EE 10, so it has jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory, not javax.validation.ValidatorFactory. The javax namespace is used in Jakarta EE 8/JavaEE 8 or lower, since Jakarta EE 9, it uses the jakarta namespace.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/orm/hibernate.html#:~:text=As%20of%20Spring%20Framework%206.0,branch%20in%20that%20Hibernate%20generation.
but here said spring 6 support hibernate ORM 5.6?

FYI: WildFly is a full stack Jakarta EE server which already provides among others Hibernate out the box, so you don't need to do that manually. Just remove every manually included Jakarta EE API/impl dependency from your project and you're good to go. WildFly is different than e.g. Tomcat for which you indeed need to cram a lot of explicit dependencies into the project. Make sure you don't get confused from the average Spring+Hibernate-related information found on the Internet because that's more than often tailored for Tomcat users. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096

@BalusC but at least need the jar at compile time in eclipse, like provided scope in maven ? and as spring, Hibernate is not Jakarta ee implementation,  wildfly 28 still contain spring and hibernate jar?

WildFly is a Jakarta EE impl. Hibernate is a JPA impl. WildFly uses Hibernate as JPA impl (and thus not e.g. EclipseLink or OpenJPA etc). Just click the link in my previous comment (and the links therein) for further explanation wrt Maven config/scopes. Spring is NOT part of Jakarta EE API so you need to provide it yourself via webapp.
