FAILURE - Application deployed to context path [/webapp-session], but the context failed to start
Hi everyone and have a good day. I learning Java and I had started learn Tomcat, so a day I ran the server in the terminal and I having a failure that say: FAILURE - Application deployed to context path [/webapp-session], but the context failed to start. I don't understand why that appears and I tried search where is the error in my code but I did not find it. I would like that someone to help me. I going to show you some screenshots. Other thing, the Tomcat server indicates fails to scan in files .JAR, for example:
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar, jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar, jackson-annotations-2.12.3.jar, jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar, jakarta.el-api-4.0.0.jar, jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar. Among many others. This happen when I try to make a connection pooling using the documentacion about JDNI DataSource of Apache Tomcat.
For example:
29-Jun-2024 11:14:04.656 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan JAR [war:file:/C:/Users/Gateway/Desktop/Lenguajes%20de%20programacion/Master%20Java/JavaEE/apache-tomcat-11.0.0-M20/webapps/webapp-session.war*/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.12.3.jar] from /WEB-INF/lib

My code in my package util for the connection to the Databases:
public class ConexionBaseDatosDS {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        Context initContext = null;
        initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/mysqlDB");
        return ds.getConnection();

    }
}


Just an observation: tomcat-11.0.0-M20 - It appears that you are using a beta release of Tomcat (version 11). Instead, use the latest stable release (version 10).

Apart from that, there really isn't the relevant info in your question for effective troubleshooting. Maybe to start with... "where is the error...?" - Have you looked in catalina.out (see here)?

Indeed, the answer is in server logs. Most likely simply user permissions are wrong/corrupted which is usually a consequence of incorrectly installing Tomcat as a Window service as if it were a production server instead of just unzipping the zip file. And, I strongly recommend you to carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295096 in order to learn what exactly Jakarta EE is before it's too late. Tomcat is namely not a full fledged Jakarta EE platform and you'd need to do a lot of things differently and you can only deploy custom stacks, not stock JEE apps.

Try unzipping your Tomcat to path WITHOUT spaces. Using folders with spaces is not recommended and very error prone Lenguajes%20de%20programacion/Master%20Java

You shouldn't use InitailContext in Java EE app but rather resource injection like this:
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/postgresql")
    private DataSource dataSource;

Also use server that supports Jakarta EE like OpenLiberty.
Here you have some samples showing OpenLiberty, Jakarta EE, and JDBC:

Example server configuration
Detailed JDBC OpenLiberty feature
Other usefule OpenLiberty guides


That's true, but this doesn't answer the corrupted JAR file issue. The InitialContext code snippet isn't even reached/executed at all. The same problem would still manifest if OP were to remove the InitialContext code snippet while keeping the same JAR files.

@BalusC I agree, but its kind of waste of time diagnosing what went wrong while trying to make Jakarta EE server out of Tomcat. If someone needs EE then should use TomEE or other EE server, if not , then correctly install Tomcat and stick to supported features.
